# Return KDB query to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, kdb, qpython, qpython3

I would like to extract data from a KDB database and place into a dataframe. My query runs fine in qpad, no issues; just need to write it into my Pandas dataframe. My code:

```
from qpython import qconnection

# Create the connection and save the handle to a variable
q  = qconnection.QConnection(host = 'wokplpaxvj003', port = 11503, username = 'pelucas', password = 'Dive2600', timeout = 3.0)
try:
    # initialize connection
    q.open()
    print(q)
    print('IPC version: %s. Is connected: %s' % (q.protocol_version, q.is_connected()))

    df = q.sendSync('{select from quote_flat where date within (2019.08.14;2019.08.14), amendment_no = (max;amendment_no)fby quote_id}')

    df.info()

finally:
    q.close()
```

It fails on the `df.info()` raising `AttributeError: 'QLambda' object has no attribute 'info'` so I guess the call is not successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've sent only a lambda but with no instruction to execute that lambda. Two options:

1. Don't make it a lambda

```
df = q.sendSync('select from quote_flat where date within (2019.08.14;2019.08.14), amendment_no = (max;amendment_no)fby quote_id')
```

2. Execute the lambda

```
df = q.sendSync('{select from quote_flat where date within (2019.08.14;2019.08.14), amendment_no = (max;amendment_no)fby quote_id}[]')
```

Comment: Thanks @terrylynch. I went with the second option which returned records. I can see values in the df when I evaluate the variable but am getting "raise AttributeError("recarray has no attribute %s" % attr): "AttributeError: recarray has no attribute info" on df.info(). It looks as if the many fields from the database have been returned to a single field so df is a 1xm matirx Is there a way to parse the values so a n x m grid is returned from q.sendSync?

Comment: I'm not experienced enough with qpython to know what that error would be but I do recall simply using `q` for synchronous calls rather than `q.sendSync` - perhaps try that? From my experience I would issue a call like `df = q('select from table')` and then I would loop through the result row by row using indexing

Comment: Thanks Terry will try that